# CsvHelper adding leading zeros to string when reading from file

Tags: csv, csvhelper

I am having a problem reading csv data from a file that looks like this;

Code,Name,Country,Exchange,Currency,Type,Isin

333,Midea Group Co Ltd Class A,USA,,USD,,

Using a class defined as;

```
        public class SymbolsRow
        {
            [Name("Code")]
            public string Code { get; set; }

            [Name("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Name("Country")]
            public string Country { get; set; }

            [Name("Exchange")]
            public string Exchange { get; set; }

            [Name("Currency")]
            public string Currency { get; set; }

            [Name("Type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }

            [Name("Isin")]
            public string Isin { get; set; }
        }
```

When I use `var symbolData =  symbolsCsv.GetRecord<SymbolsRow>();` the value of `symbolData.Code` is "000333" not "333" as expected.

I have seen a lot of questions about how to ensure leading zeros when using CsvHelper and Excel, but that is not the issue here.

Can somebody please tell me why it does not work as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce with **CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0**, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/w6MXRK.  What version are you using?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I wonder whether those leading spaces have something to do with the blank line between the header row and the `333,Midea Group Co Ltd Class A,USA,,USD,,` row. What happens if you manually remove the blank line?

Comment: I posted prematurely I am playing with it and yes I think it might be as you suggest. It appears that the issue is related to the fact that the file is very large, not just the first two rows I wrote in my question.
However now when I run using the same large file as yesterday I don't see the problem leading zeros - very frustrating. 
I will try to reproduce - thank you for your help.